# Проблемы с выводом содержимого на странице

Tags: html, css, meta, viewport

На всех страницах сайта все сжимается под размер экрана и отображается нормально(пример на 1 картинке). Но на одной странице контент не подстраивается под размер экрана(картинка 2). 
Если как бы отдалить страницу, то все отображается хорошо(картинка 3).
Как сделать так, чтобы сразу открывалось так же, как на третьей картинке?

[image: картинка 1]
[image: картинка 2]
[image: картинка 3]

Comment: это вопрос о том как сделать в html и css да ? или как сделать это в фотошопе ? ммм

Comment: с помощью html и css

Comment: ну тогда скажите Борис каким образом здесь помогут изображения ?надо видеть код и ссылку на сайт ...а по скринам даже Билл Гейтс ни чего не скажет